# App crashde when NO Internet connection. Crashed: com.squareup.SocketRocket.NetworkThread

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, socketrocket

**iOS App crashed when the no internet connection available and refresh the app several times.**

```
Crashed: com.squareup.SocketRocket.NetworkThread

0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18332c910 objc_msgSend + 16
1  CoreFoundation                 0x184097b34 _signalEventSync + 212
2  CoreFoundation                 0x184097a40 _cfstream_shared_signalEventSync + 460
3  CoreFoundation                 0x184107404 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
4  CoreFoundation                 0x184106c2c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 276
5  CoreFoundation                 0x18410479c __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
6  CoreFoundation                 0x184024da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
7  Foundation                     0x184a99674 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
8  SocketRocket                   0x101563560 -[_SRRunLoopThread main] (SRWebSocket.m:1742)
9  Foundation                     0x184ba9efc __NSThread__start__ + 1040
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183d85220 _pthread_body + 272
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183d85110 _pthread_body + 290
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183d83b10 thread_start + 4
```

Comment: Before making any request you need to check if connection is available. if not you need to provide a meaningful message to user.

Comment: Which library you are using for Network call. I think you wrote your UI updation code in API response, It should be in API success response.

Comment: @Vinaykrishnan Yes I gave meaningful message, but the issue is not occurring every time.

Comment: @ManishM.Mahajan I used Reachability.m/.h for network call

Comment: Is Reachability is network helping library. I think its for network check library. Sorry I cant help. I will suggest you to use Exceptional Breakpoint to check crash.